# Why is IIS 7.5 unloading an AppDomain from the AppPool

Tags: .net, iis, iis-7.5, appdomain, application-pool

I have a Windows 2008 R2 DataCenter with sp1.  It is running IIS 7.5.7600.16385

I have a .Net webapi app running under an AppPool configured under framework 4 and integrated pipeline.

I wrote a service that uses Microsoft WebAdministration to see if the w3wp.exe exists with an AppDomain having a virtual path = "MyAppName", and this works just great when I started it yesterday...except last night the service detected no "MyAppName" present.  After researching it looks like "MyAppName" unloaded from the AppPool (and my service spammed alert email all night). It looks like it unloaded after about 6 hours of inactivity.  The AppPool w3wp.exe was still around, and once the webapi was hit in the morning the AppDomain was loaded back by the AppPool, slight delay, but everything worked fine then and after with no delay.

My understanding is that a w3wp.exe instance is present for a configured AppPool.  And the AppPool loads in AppDomains for each app it hosts.

I understand that configuration changes and a few other things can cause the AppDomain to unload and then reload (restart of the AppDomain - at no time did my AppPool recycle, the same w3wp.exe was present always - seems to be confusion out there with these terms...)

My question is why did my AppDomain unload last night?

Is there a setting (as I said it happened after about 6 hours of inactivity last night across 12 web servers)?

We have AppPool recycling interval = 0 and idle timeout setting = 0

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tess/2008/11/06/troubleshooting-appdomain-restarts-and-other-issues-with-etw-tracing/ you can only know the cause via ETW.